# result code is zero when the parent activity calls finishActivity()

Tags: android, android-activity

I put setResult(200) in onCreate() at the child activity.

But once I call finishActivity() from the parent, I got resultCode 0.

I Don't know How to explain this situation.

```
04-25 11:52:55.191: D/TEST(28141): onActivityResult 1000 : 0 : null
```

The parent is :

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    Button b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Popup.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);

                new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Main.this.finishActivity(1000);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("TEST", "onActivityResult " + requestCode + " : " + resultCode + " : " + data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Child :

```
public class Popup extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setResult(200);

    }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

I got understand that `onActivityResult()` will be called, when the child activity ends.
And calling `finishActivity()` won't get the ActivityResult of child activity.

But I want to know correct way to get the ActivityResult(resultCode and intent data) once the child activity is destroyed by parent activity.
And Is there any reason to shouldn't do this like bellow code? (I'm just curious.)
Because It seems work fine.

I coded like this :

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    Button b;
    public static boolean closePopup = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                closePopup = false;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Popup.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);

                new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        closePopup = true;
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("TEST", "onActivityResult " + requestCode + " : " + resultCode + " : " + data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}



public class Popup extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCloseHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    Handler mCloseHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (Main.closePopup == true) {
                Popup.this.finish();
            } else {
                mCloseHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        setResult(200);
        super.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Popup` activity use

```
if(null != getParent())
    getParent().setResult(200);
else
    setResult(200);
```

instead of just `setResult(200);`

As you need to bind the data to parent activity and set the Result.

**UPDATE:**

Understand the difference between `finish()` and `finishActivity (int requestCode)`

**finish ()**

> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The
>   ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via
>   onActivityResult().

**finishActivity (int requestCode)**

> Force finish another activity that you had previously started with
>   startActivityForResult(Intent, int).

So in your case you are calling `finishActivity` on `Main` which is finishing the child activity `Popup`. Hence you are getting result code as 0 and intent as null (default values) as the data is not propagated back to Main (Parent).

I suggest you to modify your code as follows and try:

1. Remove timer block ie. call to finishActivity.
2. call `finish()` after `setResult(200);` in `Popup`.

   ```
   if(null != getParent())
      getParent().setResult(200);
   else
      setResult(200); 

   finish();
   ```

**UPDATE 2 :**
Let me explain it further.

When you start the activity with the `startActivityForResult()` method call, and once the sub-activity ends, the `onActivityResult()` method on the sub-activity is called and you can perform actions based on the result.

The started activity(sub-activity) can also set a result code which the caller can use to determine if the activity was canceled or not.(Your case)

The sub-activity uses the `finish()` method to create a new intent and to put data into it. It also sets a result via the `setResult()` method call.

If the sub-activity is finished, it can send data back to its caller via an `Intent`. This is done in the `finish()` method. So you can override finish method as follows.

```
@Override
public void finish() {
  // Prepare data intent 
  Intent data = new Intent();
  // Put data in intent
  // Activity finished, return the data
  setResult(200, data);
  super.finish();
}
```

Comment: I tried getParent().setResult() , but resultCode is still 0. actually getParent() is null.

Comment: have updated my answer. See if it is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. So, Is the best way to finish child activity that sending a message via child's `Handler` from parent activity and child handles message calling `finish()`?